# Replacement evaluator contains number after replacement group

Tags: c#, regex

I want to dynamically adjust my replacement pattern and evaluator:

```
string pattern = "np";
string replacement = "ab";
string retval = Regex.Replace("Input", @"(.*)" + pattern + @"(.*)", @"$1" + replacement + @"$2";
// retval = "Iabut" => correct
string replacement = "12";
retval = Regex.Replace("Input", @"(.*)" + pattern + @"(.*)", @"$1" + replacement + @"$2";
// retval = "$112ut" => wrong
```

The problem is that in the second case my evaluator is `"$112$2"` so my first replacement group would be `$112`.

Is it possible to avoid such problems directly or do I need to put a delimiting character between my group definition and my string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a replacement argument, use

```
"${1}" + replacement.Replace("$", "$$") + "$2"
```

The braces in `${1}` will make sure the first group is referred to and `.Replace("$", "$$")` will make it work well if the replacement has `$` inside.